# How to send out signal on two wires

Tags: communication, digital-communications, dali

I have two wires for a [DALI communication bus](https://web.archive.org/web/20130627012349/http://www.dali-ag.org/c/manual_gb.pdf). The voltage between them is 16V and I want to send out commands on the two wires from the bus. My guess would be to have a simple transistor between the two wires and send out the signal from a microcontroller, but when I simulate this, it doesn't work.

[image: Simulation of circuit from MultiSim]

Here is a new simulation as @jay suggested, with the two resistors. I will research about transistors now, so it makes sense:

[image]

Comment: In real life, Q1 would now be dead.  You are asking it to short circuit the power supply.

Comment: Yes I know, but how else would I go about it? A pull-up/pull-down?

Comment: There are ways to do what you're asking, but I wouldn't recommend any of them without knowing a lot more about what you're trying to do and what your limitations are.

Comment: If you post a link to the specification for the DALI communications bus, it would make it a lot easier to answer the question.

Comment: Good start! Put a resistor between VCC and Q1. Later, put one more resister between XPO1 & Q1, too. And, then study how a TR works.

Comment: Thank you @jay, I have added two resistors and got to the expected outcome, now I will research about the transistor, so I can explain it to my professor

Comment: Yay! Thanks for reporting back to us.

Comment: DALI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Addressable_Lighting_Interface

Comment: If you want to talk on a DALI bus, you might want to research how DALI works and implement a compatible DALI interface, instead of randomly throwing transistors at it.

Comment: The likes of NXP, Atmel, Microchip and others have application notes and example designs for DALI interfaces. Seek them out and your problem is solved. If you have specific questions of a given design, then you can ask here. Unless you are doing something really obscure, you can usually find an example from the semiconductor manufacturers or on the interwebs. Another technique is to append ‘arduino’ to your search. Eg google arduino dali

Comment: @JRE Apparently shorting VCC to ground is the correct way to send a signal with DALI.  The power supply is required to current limit to 250 mA and withstand an indefinite short.  VCC is specified as being between 9.5 and 22.5 V (16 V nominal).

Comment: @AlexHajnal:  Right.  That's not what the circuit in the question does.  It has a simple voltage source rather than a current limited voltage source.  It doesn't simulate the DALI power supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments helped a bit, but I might have missed a lot of information.

However I found an [application note](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01465a.pdf) from Microchip which helped a lot and I ended up using the circuit below.

[image: image of updated circuit]